# Is size of an array flexible in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++17, cin

After declaring a character array, say `char s[20]`, and eventually getting inputs using `cin.getline(s,100)` change the size of the array to 100, change (exactly) to the number of characters entered as input, or does it change at all? What happens to the array size that I initially declared?

I'm new to programming, so your simple explanation will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: cin.getline(s,100) is an error, since s only has space for 20 chars.  Avoid C-style arrays when you can use vectors or strings

Comment: No, C++ does not have VLA:s (variable length arrays) or Flexible arrays. Use `std::string line;` and `std::getline(std::cin, line);`

Comment: Lie to your program and you will suffer. Maybe not immediately, but someday. Trust me, immediately is a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 6):

The size does not change what happens is that you are writing past the buffer size. If you write far enough through the buffer you will end up causing a buffer overflow.

You should use `std::vector` whenever you can instead of c-style arrays.

As Ted Lyngmo commented, in this case `std::string` will be better to use than std::vector or the c-style array:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I fully agree. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: No.

The size of the character array `s` doesn't changes to `100`, but when you exceed the limit of the array's length, you cause a buffer overflow, which is really bad.

Let's consider an incorrect program, which is based on your assumption:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    char s[20];

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline(s, 100);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here I just try to *expand* the size of array `s`, it actually doesn't.

If you enter an example sentence, like: `hello-world-how-are-you-today` (which contains `29` characters including a null-terminator), it'll just store:

```
hello-world-how-are-
```

And notice that it doesn't contains a `null-terminator` since all the containers are used and it just keeps reading which may cause undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: The out-of-bounds writing alone causes UB, anything could happen after that, so the reading probably never happens.

Comment: "_it'll just store_" - We don't know what it'll do exactly but it often would store all 30 characters and mess up something else in memory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, the debugger shows that it only stores till 19th array (starting from 0).

Comment: @RohanBari The debugger is probably showing you the memory you _declared_ for `s`, not the memory you actually trampled on.

Comment: @RohanBari That's specific to your debugger implementation and is nothing that you can count on. In an optimized release build you'd probably see it writing all 30.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a variable-length array.

To handle this situation, you can have below data structures.

- [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)
- [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)
- dynamic array, using [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/221022/) in C++ or [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) in C.

Click on the links, and you will find the description and usages.

Comment: Links are added for each one of them to find out the details.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't have dynamic memory. If you want dynamic memory allocation, you can use `std::string` for an array of characters, or `std::vector`.

`std::string` works like `char s[x];`, but it is more flexible and it has a few different things.

`std::vector` is basically like an array, but you can add / remove elements.

**Syntax:**

```
std::vector<type> name; // this is the classic syntax, I won't get more in-depth
```

**Example:**

```
std::vector<int> myVect;
```

You can add elements using `myVect.insert(position, element);` or something similar, I don't remember exactly, or you can use `myVect.push_back(element);` to add an element at the end of the vector.

Search it on cplusplus reference or GeeksForGeeks, you'll find a lot of information.